# Rails time duration in database and form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, time

I need to store a time duration in database and I'm not sure how to go about this. I've added a 'duration' column to my table of the type time but I don't know how to let the user fill in what he want. Basically, the duration will always be less than 24 hours and the user should be able to fill in both hours and minutes (not seconds)

Any suggestions on what to use for the form, and if using time as type is a good idea? I'll also need to count and subtract hours later on.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a clock in/out system for work and I used the [time_dif](http://rubygems.org/gems/time_diff) gem to get the number of hours. For the form I just used a number field to allow the user to put in the hour and minutes. Screen shot below of how the user would input their time.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: If this helps answer your question please mark it as answered. Thanks.